# Reason for java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, arraylist, stack, indexoutofboundsexception

Any idea what is wrong with this line? `outStr[i]=(String) s.pop();`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringWordReverse {

    public String[] StringToWord(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.useDelimiter(" ");
        ArrayList<String> wordList= new ArrayList<String>();
        String sc_in= sc.nextLine();
        String[] sc_split=sc_in.split(" +");
        for (int i=0; i<sc_split.length; i++){
            wordList.add(sc_split[i]);
        }

        String[] stringArr= new String[wordList.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<wordList.size(); i++){
            stringArr[i]= wordList.get(i);
        }
        return stringArr;


    }

    public String[] reverseWords(String[] words){
        Stack<String> s= new Stack<String>();
        String[] outStr=new String[words.length];
        for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
            s.push(words[i]);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
            System.out.println(s.stackSize());
            outStr[i]=(String) s.pop();
        }

        return outStr;  

    }

    public static void main(String[] argc){
        StringWordReverse swr = new StringWordReverse();


        String[] inputWords= swr.StringToWord();
        String[] outputWords=swr.reverseWords(inputWords);
        for (int i=0; i<outputWords.length;i++)
            System.out.println(outputWords[i]);


        return;
    }



}
```

And here is my Stack class:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Stack<E> {
    private ArrayList<E> s = new ArrayList<E>();
    private static int size=0;

    public void push(E item){
        s.add(item);
        size++;
        return;
    }

    public E pop(){
        size--;
        return s.remove(size-1);

    }

    public int stackSize(){
        return size;
    }


}
```

Here's the error I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:400)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)
    at XYZ.Stack.pop(Stack.java:16)
    at XYZ.StringWordReverse.reverseWords(StringWordReverse.java:35)
    at XYZ.StringWordReverse.main(StringWordReverse.java:47)
```

Comment: You don't make `size` bigger when you push, so pop always tries to take the -1th thing in the stack.  Instead of holding a separate `size` variable, why not just use `s.size()`?

Comment: Before answering anything, I would tell you to trust your IDE. The yellow underlining is not a decoration, it's a warning :D You are using raw types where you should be using generics

Comment: But now you're reducing the size before you actually pop.  So if the stack has one element, you set size to `0` and then `s.remove(size-1)` is really `s.remove(-1)`...  The backing `List` is already keeping track of its size.  Why not trust it?

Comment: @MonaJalal azurefrog has a fair point in his last comment. And it would prevent you from making mistakes on the size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some wrong things in this code :

- you use raw types instead of generics. Let the compiler help you with (most) runtime type error : `Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>()`
- in `Stack.pop`, you never check you have an element to pop. You should test it and throw an exception such as `NoSuchElementException` if the stack is empty.
- in `Stack.pop`, you are decrementing the size and then removing item `size - 1`, so you basically decremented twice. This should be : `s.remove(--size);`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on `s.remove(--size);` :) very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You are decreasing your size variable **before** you take the item from the stack using the same size variable.  So when you call pop with one item left, you reduce size to 0 and then are trying to remove the item at position -1.

Why maintain your own size variable when you already have one as part of the list?

Answer (score 1):

try changing this part of the code:

```
public E pop(){
    size--;
    return s.remove(size-1);
}
```

to this:

```
public E pop(){
    return s.remove(size--);
}
```

thats the error.